# How to retrieve user roles from Azule AD MSAL accessToken?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-msal

I created two applications in Azure portal: one is client app, and another one is web api. I'm getting accessToken in SPA and then using this token to make requests to web api.
I created roles for web api app and then assigned one of these roles to myself.

Inside web api I can verify user roles for every endpoint using decorators  `[Authorize(Roles = "Reader, Editor, Admin")]`, but I also need access to these roles in my client application. I checked this accessToken using jwt.ms and it has `"roles": ["Admin"]` after parsing. But how can I get these roles in client application using JS?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: @StanleyGong, yes, thank you, really appreciate it, but still curious why they don't provide these roles in response object if it's so easy to extract from token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to extract Claims from accessToken payload, just try the code below:

```html
<html>
                <body>
                                <div id="payload"></div>
                  
                </body>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-base64@3.2.4/base64.min.js" ></script>
                <script>
                var token= "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkRJakFBSUpjNmZnMlkzd0dObkpRSEpXWjhXX1FGOG5Zd2lfVTFfOVhMejgifQ.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.Fa5EX4b3Px5Xan_qs1a8I6DC8lLxu78AhyQu9-yqE68TCSrNt7QrAWbUPvFPC8TFErDb84FUPDvtLkVS7Q4mEM9dbAGRtxXoSkZa85TPLj6PxYmE61pONwwf971UZiFjLKjkhqVsbpC1Zbgvx5Z_vfFBlrlbxohzZHQuvBI6rqhLeZebvr9bitsIHgFvHJIh-6QgstII8ExQbXqLHzOB0E9e1nT4O7SaW4hnxEr-nKsnpsEbYZ-6LsIcR4svVyEsTp9_YoslU2hAHN0tLuJL-AR74wqUFjO79pUa3fCjiur207cEcvkthbahzeqVY-gqJGIGndZmxo3a3Rf0QEbWlg"
                
                 var token_parts = token.split(".")
                var token_payload = JSON.parse(Base64.decode(token_parts[1]));
                
                 document.getElementById("payload").innerHTML = Base64.decode(token_parts[1]) + "</br> </br> name claim:" + token_payload.name;
                </script>

</html>
```

Basically,a token is composed by 3 parts, separated by "." ,and the payload is stored in the second part, you can just Base64 decode it to get its content

Comment: had to use `atob()` instead of `Base64.decode()`  as my linter wouldn't recognise `Base64`

Answer (score 0):

`atob()` is deprecated, you will have to use `window.atob()` or you could use `Buffer` tools for backend rendering