# Authenticate azure python function to call it from AJAX request without exposing a token or key

Tags: javascript, python, azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a `Python Azure Function` and calling it via `JS` code hosted as an `App Service` on Azure.

I need to setup `azure active directory authentication` on this function.
I have configured azure active directory authentication in azure function app and azure app service and enabled CORS on both but still facing CORS issue

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.windows.net' redirected from 'azure-function-url' from origin 'app-service-url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Basically I want authentication for azure python function so that I can call it from AJAX request without exposing a token in app service?
Am I doing anything wrong?

Also is there a way I could return the logged in user's email-id with an azure function while using azure active directory authentication for that azure function? I can find a code sample in c#, below it is.

```
laimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
string welcome = string.Format("Welcome, {0} {1}!", 
cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value, `cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value);`
```

Now the issue is, I need to use Python to do this and I can't find a sample online. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? or maybe help translate this code.

Comment: It is not supported call Azure AD endpoint directly from SPA, use msal.js to do that. Details see this sample: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core

Comment: okay will try this.

Comment: @StanleyGong Also is there a way I could return the logged in user's email-id with an azure function while using azure active directory authentication for that azure function?

Comment: Sure, generally, user's email-id will be involved in tokens that you get from Azure AD, for how to get this, just refer to my previous post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658682/how-to-retrieve-user-roles-from-azule-ad-msal-accesstoken/64659339#64659339

Comment: @StanleyGong Thanks for the answer! Can you tell me how can I get the access token that I get from Azure AD after login within my python httptrigger azure function?

Comment: I have posted the code demo

Comment: How's going ? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: Thanks for the code but in my scenario I have to avoid exposing the token in the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple demo that calling an Azure function from html/JS code.

**Step1:** You should register an Azure AD application as your client so that you can use this app to login users and get tokens:

[image]

in this case , it will need Microsoft Graph API read user permission:
[image]

**Step2:**Create a python function with code below to test:

```
import logging
import base64
import azure.functions as func
import json


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    accessTokenPayLoad = req.headers.get("Authorization").replace("Bearer ","").split(".")[1]
    data = base64.b64decode(accessTokenPayLoad + '==')
    jsonObj = json.loads(data)
    upn = jsonObj['upn']
    return func.HttpResponse("hello, " + upn)
```

Basically, this function just read user's upn from access token to read user's email-id.

**Step3** After you have created the function app, please enable CORS so that it could accept requests from static HTML:
[image]

**Step4** The code below is the HTML/JS code sample that login users and get tokens to call the function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Azure Function test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.4.4/js/msal.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div >
                    
        <button id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign in</button><br/>
        <div id="WelcomeMessage"></div><br/>
        <div id="functionResult"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    
    var clientAppID = "<your client app id>"
    var tenantID = "<your tenant name/id>"
    var functionURL = "<your function url>";
    
    var demoScops = {
         scopes:["user.read"]
    }

    var msalConfig = {
             auth: {
                 clientId: clientAppID,
                 authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID
            },
             cache: {
                 cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                 storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
    };
     

    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);
             
    
    function signIn() {
     
         myMSALObj.loginPopup(demoScops).then(function (loginResponse) {
            console.log(loginResponse);
            initPage();
             
         }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
     }
     
    function initPage(){
        showWelcomeMessage();
        getGraphAccessTokenToCallFunction()
     }
     
     
     function callFunction(accessToken){

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('functionResult').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", functionURL, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        
     }
     
     
     function getGraphAccessTokenToCallFunction(){
         myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(demoScops).then(function (tokenResponse) {
         
              console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
              callFunction(tokenResponse.accessToken);
              
         }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              })
        }     
     
     function showWelcomeMessage() {
             
         var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
         divWelcome.innerHTML = 'welcome! ' + myMSALObj.account.name ;
         var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
         loginbutton.innerHTML = 'sign out';
         loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
     }
     
     
     
     
     function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
         if (error) {
             console.log(error);
         }
         else {
             if (response.tokenType === "access_token") {
                 callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphEndpoint, response.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
             } else {
                 console.log("token type is:" + response.tokenType);
             }
         }
     }
     
     function requiresInteraction(errorCode) {
         if (!errorCode || !errorCode.length) {
             return false;
         }
         return errorCode === "consent_required" ||
             errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
             errorCode === "login_required";
     }
     

     var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
     var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
     var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
     var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
     var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
     var isEdge = msedge > 0;

     var loginType = isIE ? "REDIRECT" : "POPUP";
     
     if (loginType === 'POPUP') {
          if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
              initPage()
          }
     }
     else if (loginType === 'REDIRECT') {
         document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
              myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
         };
         if (myMSALObj.getAccount() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
              initPage()
          }
     } else {
         console.error('Please set a valid login type');
     }
     
     

      function signOut() {
          window.localStorage.clear();
          myMSALObj.logout();
      }
    
</script>

</html>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I am authenticating end-user with Azure AD credentials(email and password) not with token so in this case how will I get the user email ?

Comment: yes i am using login with azure active directory for authentication hence need to input username and password

Comment: Hi @Gaurav I have updated my answer with a demo. I think it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the code but in my scenario I have to avoid exposing the token in the front end?

Comment: @Gaurav, tokens will never be exposed in this demo, this is the most standard way to login users and get access tokens from Azure AD to call an API. Your tokens will never be exposed as they are not hard coded in code, only users sigin successfully will be able to get tokens from Azure AD.

Comment: @Gaurav, how's going? Has your issue been solved? If my answer is helpful.pls mark it

Comment: Is there a way to redirect my azure function to a url instead of giving a http response?