# What is the best practice for authenticating a HTTP request to a Python Azure Function endpoint (Azure AD JWT)?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-functions, bearer-token

Could anyone tell me what is the current best practice for authenticating a HTTP request to a Python Azure Function endpoint with Azure AD? The HTTP request is made from an SPA browser client including an attached JWT bearer token. I am not using any role-based authentication, just the basic one with an access scope.

If this was a C# function this would be quite straightforward because I could use the SDK provided by Microsoft.Identity.Web. However, I am not aware of anything similar in the case of Python, nor did I find any useful example in the Azure Samples GitHub repo.

I am also not asking about the Azure AD configuration, just the necessary code in the function itself.

Comment: Hello @Neits, Could you please refer this links ,May it helps [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions)  &  [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780969/authenticate-azure-python-function-to-call-it-from-ajax-request-without-exposing) .

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am not aware of anything similar in the case of Python, nor
> did I find any useful example in the Azure Samples GitHub repo.

To do that in python Azure function to secure with Azure AD you can find the steps with sample code as mentioned here in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions) .

For more information please refer the below links:

. [azure-functions-python-library | GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library) .

.  [Python Azure Function Web API secured by Azure AD| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/) .